# Prevent Facebook following/discarding short url to redirect page

Tags: facebook

We're trying to build a share widget for referral links (links that are essentially short urls - a.b.com/uniqueCode, which redirects to a client website but goes through our service and lets us track them) - essentially someone needs to share their own affiliate url on Facebook.

The problem is Facebook seems to always resolve the url to the final destination, and doesn't display the url we pass in. I can't find any documentation on whether there's a way to prevent this or not. We've tried both with a 301 and 302 redirect, with no change. I've tried different urls to make sure we're not seeing the result of their url caching.

Is there a way to instruct Facebook (and Google Plus, Linkedin) to keep the referring link we provide?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the redirect using Javascript.

Also, you might be able to do it by showing the social networks' crawlers different pages based on their useragent or IP or so – look into your webserver logs or so and check what happens there immediately after you've posted the link.

Comment: We can't do the redirects with javascript, we'll have an immense number of affiliates using these urls (hundreds of thousands) and that's too inefficient. We've discussed watching for the servers fetching the url but they also try to grab content so we'd have to proxy the content, and I don't trust that whitelisting their hostnames/IPs is stable/future-proof.

Comment: You could try first doing the redirect using JS and then, as soon as the link is in all relevant social networks, switch it to an HTTP redirect.

Comment: You could even automate that: Whoever wants to post a link in a social network generates a new unique one. Then, he submits it to the network. After ten requests or so, the link automatically switches over to an HTTP redirect.